# how to get a specific types of user from a users collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using nodeJs with mongoDB. I have a user collection where I am saving 2types of users (student/teacher). So now I want to get all users which type is student

Comment: Are you using `mongoose` or just the `mongodb` driver? Have you already connected to the database and/or created a model? Have you gotten to the point where you can make queries?

Comment: You can write a `find` query on the users collection.

Comment: in javascript `users.find(elm => elm.type == "student");`

Answer (score 0):

Below query will find all the user with the type "student".
replace "student" with "teacher" and you will get the list of all teacher's.

```
users.find({ userType: 'student' });
```